# Balls in a separable metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable metric space and let $(r_i)$ be a sequence of positive reals. Denote by $(x_n)$ a countable dense subset of $X$. Is it true that $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K(x_n, r_n)$?

Comment: So $K(x_n,r_n)$ is the open ball $B(x_n,r_n)$ I imagine.

Comment: Sure, the open ball.

Comment: What is true and somehow related is that the countable set of all open balls $B(x_n,2^{-k})$ for $n\geq 1$ and $k\geq 1$ is a basis for the topology induced by the metric, making it second countable. In particular, of course, $X=\bigcup_{n,k}B(x_n,2^{-k})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $X=\mathbb R$, $x_n$ to be the rationals and $r_i=2^{-i}$.

Comment: Is it clear that some irrational doesn't belong to the union?

Comment: @usao This set has finite measure.

Comment: The measure can be made as small as you wish!